# How to score a small set of docs in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I would like to compute the scores for a small number of documents (rather than for the entire collection) for a given query. My attempt, as follows, returns 0 scores for each document, even though the queries I test with were derived from the terms in the documents I am trying to score. I am using Lucene 3.0.3.

```
List<Float> score(IndexReader reader, Query query, List<Integer> newDocs ) {
List<Float> scores = new List<Float>();
IndexSearcher searcher = reader.getSearcher();
Collector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(newDocs.size(), true);
Weight weight = query.createWeight(searcher);
Scorer scorer = weight.scorer(reader, true, true);
collector.setScorer(scorer);
float score = 0.0f;
for(Integer d: newDocs) {
    scorer.advance(d);
    collector.collect(d);
    score = scorer.score();
    System.out.println( "doc: " + d + "; score=" + score);
    scores.add( new Float(score) );
}
return scores;
}
```

I am obviously missing something in the setup of scoring, but I cannot figure out from the Lucene source code what that might be.

Thanks in advance,

Gene

Comment: Why don't you use a Filter?  See http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20int%29

Comment: Yes. You should first try a high-level approach, such as filtering, before delving into the low-level scoring. Or we are missing something. In that case, please tell us why you need to score just this set; Is this performance? or a special application? Still, in both these cases I believe you can find an existing mechanism in Lucene that is easier to use.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to improve performance. I have a previously-cached result list of approx 1000 docs, and I know that the newly-added docs are a likely match to this query. I would like to do the minimal amount of computation to update the search results.

Comment: Thanks for the Filter tip. It seems to be the right way to go, but I am having a problem actually getting results out of it. I created a SortedVIntList DocIdSet which I return in an anonymous Filter() class. When I step through the code, the docid I put in (14186) appears to be two off from what the reader has (14188), which means the document never gets scored. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a filter, and do a [search with that filter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20int%29). Then just iterate through the results as you would with a normal search - Lucene will handle the filtering.

In general, if you are looking at DocIds, you're probably using a lower-level API than you need to, and it's going to give you trouble.